# VSCode and Jupyter Notebooks on WSL2. Previewing a notebook and then closing the window results in a "unsaved changes" warning. What is this?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

VSCode and Jupyter Notebooks on WSL2. Previewing a notebook and then closing the window results in a "unsaved changes" warning. What is this?

What did I do?

- open a project with vs code `code /path/to/project`
- `git pull` to make sure everything is up to date
- use file explore to find a `.ipynb` file
- click once on a notebook file

  - file opens with name in italic *file.ipynb*
  - file then changes to straight with unsaved changes notifier `file.ipynb *`
- click the "x" close button for the file
- "Do you want to save changes"

I didn't change anything. What is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Do other types of files have this problem? How about trying to reinstall vscode

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT no it seems to be notebook specific

Comment: I just clicked on my `.ipynb` file and this problem really occurred, but it only appeared once. Maybe it did have some problems, you can try switch to pre-release version in extension store.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT no I tried both and it is still the same

Comment: I use version `v2022.9.1303220346`, it doesn't happen now.